# Function that counts sentences

Tags: python

```
file = open(file_variable)
n = 0
line = file.readline()

while line != "":
    for ch in line:
        if ch in '.?!':
            n += 1
    file.readline()

return n

file_variable.close()
```

When I try and print n in the main program, it doesn't return anything. Can someone give me advice on what I'm doing wrong. I'm a bit confused on how reading txt files works..

Main program

```
from functions import sentence_count

file_variable = 'pelee.txt'

n = sentence_count(file_variable)

print(n)
```

Comment: You never print `n`.

Comment: I attempt to print n in the main function

Comment: Show us your full code.

Comment: @AlexVincent Where is your main functioin then?

Comment: Show us your full, unedited code. I presume the first code snippet is in a function? Show us that entire function, including its signiture

Comment: This is the full code. Just a beginner programming class just simply counts the . ? and ! in a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the `line` variable to the next line of the file:

```
while line != "":
    for ch in line:
        if ch in '.?!':
            n += 1
    line = file.readline()
```

I would instead iterate over lines of the filelike object like this:

```
f = open('example.txt', 'r')

for line in f:
    if '.' in line or '?' in line or '!' in line:
        n += 1
```

This works because Python's [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function returns an iterable object (`io.TextIOBase`) that allows you to navigate the contents of the file in a for loop. Each item returned by the iterable is the next line of the file. You can just check the char that you're looking to find in the `line` variable.

Comment: Yeah that works. Thank you. Can you explain in more detail on how to do this in one for loop?

Comment: It will not work if you have multiple sentences in one line.